# convert_tz change timestamp in 1 hour

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have used `convert_tz` to insert local date and time into MYSQL table. But there is an issue and it will change time in 1 hour. I don't know when it changing and why.

Example:

Priviesly used - `CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'UTC', '+10:30')` to get local time 10:00AM

Now used - `CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'UTC', '+9:30')` to get local time 10:00AM

When I create website I used `CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'UTC', '+10:30')` to get local date and time. But from today I need to change all `CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'UTC', '+10:30')` to `CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'UTC', '+9:30')` to get correct local date and time. Otherwise time is 1 hour added.

How to solve this issue?

UPDATE: I am using inmotion hosting.

UPDATE 2:

I am using to get date and time following code in PHP.

```
$lastdatepost = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Colombo'));
$lastdatepost = $lastdatepost->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

This will effect with above `CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'UTC', '+10:30')` SQL code and both date and time different which is 1 hour added. Then give error.

Comment: It sounds like something has the wrong idea of what time it is in UTC because they're getting there by converting time that is stored in local time?  India doesn't do DST/summer time, so the problem isn't with that time zone... are you on Windows by any chance?

Comment: yes I am using windows

Answer (score 1):

UTC offsets change over the course of the year in most places around the globe due to Daylight Saving Time aka Summer Time. India isn't one of those places, but the US went on DST today, so the timing is suspicious.

What is your application? If PHP and MySQL have different ideas of what time it is, that implies to me that one of them must be storing local time and have an incorrect offset to UTC. Does your application perhaps run on Windows?

Comment: it is use for signup, login, post, comments etc.

Comment: I am using inmotion hosting and it servers run in linux